# Why is my IIR URLRewrite still shows the ?title= in the URL address?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, coldfusion, url-rewrite-module, commonspot

The URLRewrite is "sort of" working. If I take out the **?title=** from the https://devbox.mysite.com/?title=test-article and just have it as **https://devbox.mysite.com/test-article**, the page would still loads fine. However, the problem is, it still shows https://devbox.mysite.com/?title=test-article on the client's URL address. I don't understand that it's working but then it's still showing the actual URL on the client's browser. Below is my URLRewrite rule. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

```
<rule name="KB-rewrite" enabled="true">
    <match url="^kb/article/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="1" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="kb/article/?title={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

I thought I figured it out yesterday but that wasn't it. I re-edited this post because I think this is related to ColdFusion and perhaps our CommonSpot CMS. The question is, why is it showing ?titlte= in the URL when without it, it would still works? What could have caused this behavior? Where can I start troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this time I figured out it out. IIS URLRewrite works as it supposed to since if I removed the ?title=, the page still loads. The problem was, in the search result hyperlink, I put ?ititle= as part of the URL so when a user clicked on the result, it would show the URL as containing the ?title= in it. Since the URLRewrite is working as it should, all I had to do was remove the ?title= from each result's hyperlink and my problem is resolved.